# python compare each 2bytes in some portion of data

Tags: python, comparison, byte

In python, assume that there is data when I run...

```
search = target.readframes(2205)
```

Each frame consist of 2 bytes. I want to compare each 2-byte value and extract highest 2 values in the range.

For example, if the data looks like this...

```
0000|0001|0002|0008|0007|000F|000D|000A|00FB|00FC|00FA|00F9|00F8|00D7|00C3|0000
```

Then the result would extract `000F` and `00FC`

Could someone please help me achieve this. Any answers or helpful advise would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use only [`bytes`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0358/) objects if you deal with binary data. They require Python 2.6+.

Example

```
data = b"\x42\x43\x44\x45"
print(data[0:2], data[2:4])
```

And yes, you can use normal compare operations with bytes.

I am not sure that kind of object is returned by your `readframes` but if it is not bytes by design you should convert it to bytes. You can just use `data = bytes(obj)`.

**Do not use strings to process binary data**.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you handle audio data (assuming `target` is a [`wave.Wave_read`](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html#wave-read-objects) object), and want to find the maximum value for each channel.

```
import audioop

channel_l= audioop.tomono(search, 2, 1.0, 0.0)
channel_r= audioop.tomono(search, 2, 0.0, 1.0)
max_l= audioop.max(channel_l, 2)
max_r= audioop.max(channel_r, 2)
```

If yes, you should be more explicit in your questions; if not, feel free to downvote as not useful, people :)